# getting heap corruption error when trying to free memory in C

Tags: c, for-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior

i have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int* create_arr(int start, int end) {
    int length = end - start, i = start, j;
    int* arr;
    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("memory allocation problem");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (j=0; i <= end; i++, j++) {
        arr[j] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}
void main() {
    int num, num2;
    int *arr;
    scanf_s("%d %d", &num, &num2);
    arr = create_arr(num, num2);
    for (int i = 0; i <= num2 - num; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

for this code the part where i allocate the memory and set values into it works fine but when i add the very last line:

```
free(arr);
```

it makes an error message popup that says:
"debug error, heap corruption detected"
im wondering what im doing wrong when freeing the memory and would love some help on this.

Comment: Whenever you use a condition like `i <= end` in a loop iterating over an array, it's most likely wrong as it commonly includes one element beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Do you want to include values `{start, .., end}` in your array or `{start, .., end-1}`?

Answer (score 1):

This for loop

```
for (j=0; i <= end; i++, j++) {
    arr[j] = i;
}
```

is incorrect because the array has end - start elements according to the value of the variable `length`

```
int length = end - start, i = start, j;
```

The condition in the loop shall be either `j < length` or `i < end`.

```
for (j=0; j < length; i++, j++) {
    arr[j] = i;
}
```

Or you need increase the value of `length` by one.

In general the loop as written confuses readers of the code.

You could write instead

```
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr[i] = start++;
}
```

Also the condition `i <= num2 - num` in this for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= num2 - num; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}
```

is incorrect by the same reason as the loop pointed to above. It must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < num2 - num; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
}
```

You should check within the function that the value of the parameter `end` at least is not less than the value of the parameter `start`. And if the dynamically allocated array must contain values in the range `[start, end]` inclusively  then the memory allocation should look like

```
int length = end - start + 1;
arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length );
```

The function can be defined in one of the following ways provided that the range must include the both values of `start` and `end`.

```
int * create_arr( int start, int end ) 
{
    int *arr = NULL;

    if ( !( end < start ) )
    {
        int length = end - start + 1;

        arr - malloc( lengh * sizeof( int ) );

        if ( arr != NULL )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
            {
                arr[i] = start++;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

or

```
int * create_arr( int start, int end ) 
{
    if ( end < start )
    {
        int tmp = start;
        start = end;
        end = tmp;
    }

    int length = end - start + 1;

    int *arr - malloc( lengh * sizeof( int ) );

    if ( arr != NULL )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        {
             arr[i] = start++;
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: @Gerhardh You are right. I was not attentive.:)